# How to configure ARR under IIS 10 without ARR icon in IIS mgmt console

Tags: iis, proxy, arr

after installing ARR module and URL rewrite in IIS 10 (Windows Server 2016) the icon for ARR configuration don't appear. (s. screenshot)
Of course, I tried already several restarts of the machine.
Any help will be appreciated.

Greets.

[image: IIS10 ARR mgmt bug]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something off with your install? When I installed ARR on IIS 10 the icon came up right away without any restarts.

Did you stop the IIS service first?

```
net stop was /y
```

Did you install the IIS 10 ARR dependencies first?

According to [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47333) (see "Install Instructions"):

```
ARR is dependent on several components:
URL Rewrite
External Cache module
```

---

In a nutshell, this worked for me:

1. `net stop was /y`
2. Install the [URL Rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). It should install
   without any problem.
3. Install the [External Cache module](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/4/1/3415F3F9-5698-44FE-A072-D4AF09728390/ExternalDiskCache_amd64_en-US.msi), it will complain when
   installed on IIS 10 and demand only IIS 7. This can be handled by
   updating the IIS version registry key `HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\MajorVersion` from 10 to 7, then do the
   install, then reverting it back to 10.
4. Finally, install the [latest ARR module](https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/9/8/E9849D6A-020E-47E4-9FD0-A023E99B54EB/requestRouter_amd64.msi) (v3.0 currently).
5. `net start was /y`
6. `net start w3svc /y`

Comment: Wow, what a pain.   External Cache module link is broken.  Using the registry editor to trick it into thinking it's 3 versions earlier doesn't sound like something I want to do in production anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is actually with the Web Platform installer. When you add ARR 3.0 and click install it will say that it installed the ARR and it prerequisites however I discovered  that was not the case. It did install URL Rewrite and it did install External cache plugins but it did not complete (or correctly at least) the ARR install.

The solution for me was to go back to WPI, select the ARR 3.0 to Add it again and run the install again.

Then close the IIS Manager, run iisreset (I did it just as a precaution) and open IIS Manager again. You should see the Application Request Routing Cache icon under IIS section within your server node (Features tab -> IIS section).

Now, this is misleading because it is not only cache behind this icon, it is also the proxy feature. Open the feature (double click) and you should see cache settings. The proxy feature however, is located on the right hand side under Actions - Proxy - Server Proxy Settings. Click that link and there you now have an option to enable the (reverse) proxy feature of ARR.

HTH